# Outlook not saving attachment via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have some VBA code that actually works fine on my machine, but not my clients. Where it gets hung up is the opening of an email attachment and saving it to a location on his computer.

```
For Each nm in file_names 'file_names is just an array of strings
    found_file=False
    curr_date=CDate("1-1-9999")
    For Each olItem in olItems
        If olItem.ReceivedTime < curr_date and olItem.SenderEmailAddress=email and TypeName(olItem)="MailItem" then
            Set olAttach=olItem.attachments.Item(1)
            If not olAttach is Nothing then
                If olAttach.Filename Like nm & ".*" then
                    found_file=True
                    curr_date=olItem.ReceivedTime
                end if
            end if
        end if
    Next
    If found_file then
        olAttach.SaveAsFile pth & olAttach.Filename 'errors out here
        ...
```

The error message is `Cannot save the attachment` and does not specify a reason.

I have tried to have him enable all macros, switch off protected view options, restart excel and outlook, try different file locations to save to, there are no double \ that occur when file path is concatenated with the file name, and I made sure he wasn't using a Mac. Apparently one of the attachment files does open but it just refuses to save.

Comment: What is pth? it seems to be nothing

Comment: It is a string of the form "C:\Place_to_store_files\".

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to attach? Perhaps it's too large?

Comment: @dwirony It is a 51K xls file. I'm not trying to attach it; I'm trying to save it to a location on my PC. Again, it works fine on my PC, but not on another. I think I must be looking for reasons a file would save using this code on one machine, but not another.

Comment: @dwirony And, actually, it looks like some files are saving and some are not. There are 7 emails (with one attachment each) and the first 3 are not saving and the last 4 are. I managed to see that this was able to happen when I added `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: @MattCremeens If I were you, I'd try breaking up this `If` statement to see if one of the arguments is failing, resulting in no attachment being set: `If olItem.ReceivedTime < curr_date and olItem.SenderEmailAddress=email and TypeName(olItem)="MailItem" then`

Comment: @dwirony Except if there is no attachment being set, then `found_file` isn't set to `True` and therefore the code causing the error shouldn't be reached.

Comment: @MattCremeens Ah I see now. What about putting an `Exit For` after `curr_date=olItem.ReceivedTime`? After you've got a match, might as well exit the loop, no?

Comment: @dwirony I thought about that but the reason I want it to keep looking is in case it finds a newer email with the same attachment.

Comment: When you put `Debug.Print pth & olAttach.Filename` after `If found_file Then`, does it print a valid folder path to the immediate window?

Comment: @dwirony I believe so. I had my client hover over `pth` and `olAttach` and all appeared fine there. Plus some files are saving. 4 of the 7 are.

Comment: The system drive requires admin privileges for writing (C:). I'd suggest choosing another drive or folder. Or just try to run Outlook with admin privileges. Does it help?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I can try it, but does that explain why some files saved and others did not?

Comment: Looks like the file path/name string passed to the `SaveAsFile` method is not well-formed path.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file path/name string passed to the SaveAsFile method is not a well-formed path. For example, the `FileName` may contains forbidden symbols and etc. Try to use the following code as a test:

```
Sub SaveAttachment()
Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments

Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
If Not TypeName(myInspector) = "Nothing" Then
    If TypeName(myInspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem
        Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
        'Prompt the user for confirmation
        Dim strPrompt As String
        strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder, it will be overwritten with this copy of the file."
        If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
            myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & _
            myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "The item is of the wrong type."
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this approach but I am not sure if my client can test it before Monday. I'm curious, though, as to why all files save on my machine and only 4 save on his, while 3 do not.